# I²S Pins on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: gpio, audio, pi-3

I looked at the schematics of the Raspberry Pi 3 [here](https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/rpi3/raspberry-pi-3-b-reduced-schematics.pdf) but couldn't figure out which Pins are what, to use the [I²S Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%C2%B2S).

Which Pin-Numbers are for:

- Bit clock line?
- Word clock line?
- Multiplexed data line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GPIO 18-21 are simplest.

```
18 PCM_CLK  (pin 12)
19 PCM_FS   (pin 35)
20 PCM_DIN  (pin 38)
21 PCM_DOUT (pin 40)
```

[BCM2835 ARM Peripherals](http://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bcm2835/BCM2835-ARM-Peripherals.pdf) page 102.

Comment: Nice! I didn't saw that table. Thanks, you did help alot.

Comment: I just realized you did link the datasheet of the BCM2835 but the RPi3 runs with the BCM2837. There for this information is probably incorrect? But i can't find the datasheet for the BCM2837.

Comment: @besnep The GPIO on all the Pis are identical.  They all have 54 GPIO with the same capabilities.  The only difference is which are routed to the expansion header.  The routing is the same for all Pis with the 40 pin expansion header (Pi Zero/A+/B+/2/3).