# Is this RPi DAC compatible to RPi 3?

Tags: audio, compatibility

I bought and used this DAC for a long time on my RPi 1 B+: 
https://www.audiophonics.fr/fr/dac-diy/audiophonics-dac-sabre-es9023-v22-i2s-vers-analogique-24bit192khz-p-8396.html

Recently I bought a RPi and was wondering if I could use the DAC on my RPi 3. From what I read, the head phone output is still very bad.

Comment: Likely yes. Related: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/47799/19949 and https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/79870/19949

Comment: Have you tried?